# Atom object styles Less, change color of first string, leading string before colon,

Tags: css, less, atom-editor

Inside my style i want to change color of string before colon `:` but after colon i have another string with default color:

```
{
//color:
//to cahnge    defult 
  "code"     : "007",
  "name"     : "Bond",
  "fullName ": "James Bond"
}
```

I want to change colors of

> code, name, fullName

with or without quotation marks.

html of `"code":"007"`:

```html
 <span class="string quoted double js">
        <span class="punctuation definition string begin js">"</span>
        code
        <span class="punctuation definition string end js">"</span>
      </span>
      <span class="keyword operator js">:</span>
      <span class="string quoted double js">
        <span class="punctuation definition string begin js">"</span>
        007
        <span class="punctuation definition string end js">"</span>
      </span>
```

[image: What I want]

Want to change color text inside quotation marks. other marks colors is my paint skills issue.

It is for Atom styles so I can't change html code.

Is there a way to change string before colon `:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this and let me know if this what you was looking for!

```css
span.keyword.operator.js + span.string.quoted.double.js{
  color:#ff2233;
}

span.string.quoted.double.js{
  color:#00ff00;
}
span.punctuation.begin,span.punctuation.end{
  color:#333;
}
```

```html
<span class="string quoted double js">
        <span class="punctuation definition string begin js">"</span>
        code
        <span class="punctuation definition string end js">"</span>
      </span>
      <span class="keyword operator js">:</span>
      <span class="string quoted double js">
        <span class="punctuation definition string begin js">"</span>
        007
        <span class="punctuation definition string end js">"</span>
      </span>

<span class="string quoted double js">
        <span class="punctuation definition string begin js">"</span>
        code
        <span class="punctuation definition string end js">"</span>
      </span>
      <span class="keyword operator js">:</span>
      <span class="string quoted double js">
        <span class="punctuation definition string begin js">"</span>
        007
        <span class="punctuation definition string end js">"</span>
      </span>
```

Comment: This affected only last line where "James Bond" changed color to green #00ff00 007, Bond does'nt change to green, code, name, fullName does'nt change to red #ff0000

Comment: In Atom styles I can't change html. Is there a way to change something in less if next char is a colon

Comment: let me check this again for you

Comment: please check my updated answer , now you can select the element just after the colon as you suggested :)